# awk search value and get column

Tags: search, awk

Using awk I want to get columns starting with `/acq/old/*`.

**file1**

```
z y x / ACQ / old / a.zip y
z y t / ACQ / old / a.zip x
```

The fourth column

**file2**

```
z y / ACQ / old / a.zip 10
z y / ACQ / old / a.zip 20
```

the third column

...

**file n**

```
z y w t / ACQ / old / x.zip 100
z y f r / ACQ / old / w.zip 200
```

The fifth column

I want to do following an operation.

```
for myfile in ls *. txt
do
  awk '??' $ myfile
  other processes
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sed` to get rid of leading columns:

```
sed 's@^[^/]*@@' input
```

This is `awk` solution:

```
awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '{$1=""}1' input
```